# Prevent columns from resizing contents

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a metro UI style tile grid for a website, and I'm having some difficulty keeping sizes"static". I'm currently using CSS3 columns to order the divs from top down then left to right. The only problem I'm having right now is that I can make the column GAP static, but most browsers still attempt to resize the divs inside the columns

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("div.dashboard").mousewheel(function(event, delta){
                this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);

                event.preventDefault();
            });


        });

    </script>
    <style>
        .tile
        {
            margin: 2px;
            display: inline-block;
            column-break-inside: avoid;
            -ie-column-break-inside: avoid;
            -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
            -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            float: none;
            color: #CDCDCD;
            padding-left: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 2px solid white;
            width: 180px;
        }
        .tile:hover
        {
            border:2px solid gray;
        }
        .tile span{
            font-weight: bolder;
            padding: 3px;
            font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        }
        .ONE
        {
            background-color: #894848;
        }
        .TWO
        {
            background-color: #596996;
        }
        .THREE
        {
            background-color: #3f5f3e;
        }
        .dHeight
        {
            height: 355px;
        }
        .sHeight
        {
            height: 175px;
        }
        .dashboardContainer
        {
            columns: 150px auto;
            -moz-columns: 175px auto;
            -webkit-columns: 150px auto;
            column-gap: 4px;
            -moz-column-gap: 4px;
            -webkit-column-gap: 4px;
            height: 600px;
            //width: 3600px;
        }
        .dashboard
        {
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="dashboard">
        <div class="dashboardContainer">
           <div class="tile THREE sHeight"> 
                1
           </div>
           <div class="tile TWO sHeight"> 
                2
           </div>
           <div class="tile ONE dHeight">
            3
           </div>
           <div class="tile TWO dHeight">
            4
           </div>
           <div class="tile THREE sHeight"> 
            5
           </div>
           <div class="tile TWO sHeight">
            6
           </div>
           <div class="tile THREE dHeight">
            7
           </div>
           <div class="tile ONE sHeight">
            8
           </div>
           <div class="tile ONE sHeight"> 
            9
           </div>
           <div class="tile THREE sHeight"> 
            10
           </div>
           <div class="tile TWO sHeight"> 
            11
           </div>
           <div class="tile THREE sHeight"> 
            12
           </div>

       </div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BioRebel/SLUba/1/)

Basically, I just want to stop the divs inside from resizing when the user adjusts the size of the web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLUba/3/)

```
.tile{  
    ......
     width: 180px;
 }
```

in your css you have 180px width set for tile where as in

```
.dashboardContainer
        {
            columns: 150px auto;
            -moz-columns: 175px auto;
            -webkit-columns: 150px auto;
            column-gap: 4px;
            -moz-column-gap: 4px;
            -webkit-column-gap: 4px;
            height: 600px;
            //width: 3600px;
        }
```

you have set your columns to 150px width; this is the reason for having the resize issue

have same values for both.